# How can I stop the "setspace" package from processing a "doublespacing" documentclass option?

Tags: documentclass-writing, package-options, setspace, class-options

LaTeX does not behave as I expected with the following files.

First file:

```
\documentclass[doublespacing]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Second file:

```
\documentclass[doublespacing]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

For the first file, LaTeX gives this warning as expected:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [doublespacing].
```

However, the second file compiles without any warnings and uses double-spacing to typeset the text.

Why does the second file work? It seems like the option given to the `article` documentclass should be parsed and give a warning before the `\usepackage{setspace}` is encountered.

And a little bit of context: I'm trying to extend a document class to include a `doublespacing` (by using `\DeclareOption{doublespacing}`, etc.), but I can't configure the behavior properly because the `setspace` package picks it up as if I had done `\usepackage{doublespacing}`. Is there a way to keep `setspace` from seeing the `doublespacing` documentclass option?

Comment: As a follow-on: why doesn't `\RequirePackage[singlespacing]{setspace}` override the value given in the documentclass option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every option given in the `\documentclass` line is called *global* and is passed to all packages subsequently loaded. If the package doesn't know the option, it does nothing, otherwise it applies the option. (See `clsguide.pdf` on your TeX system or [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/clsguide.pdf) for details.)

Thus it's expected behavior: saying

```
\documentclass[doublespacing]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

is equivalent to saying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
```

(as the `article` class doesn't know the option).

If you write a class that has a `doublespacing` option, the result is that this option, when specified, is passed to all packages loaded afterwards.

However, in this particular case, you can revert the setting by `setspace` by issuing an instruction

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setstretch{<factor>}}
```

where `<factor>` is how much you like.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `\AtBeginDocument` trick didn't work because the class creates some new lengths that were based on parameters that the `setspace` package sets at load time. However, I was able to add `\singlespacing` immediately after the `\RequirePackage{setspace}` line.

Comment: @amcnabb Please, don't use doublespacing in your class. ;-)

Comment: egreg, I would hope it's clear from the fact that I'm writing/editing a document class that I'm not a fan of double-spacing. But I'm not a university bureaucrat, so what do I know about typesetting? :)

Comment: @amcnabb So true. :(

Answer (score 4):

Document options (by package or by document class) are assembled and processed as needed (if one is using the `\DeclareOption` method). Only at the start of the document - at `\begin{document}`, there is a check to see whether all options have been processed or not. From [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), the following is processed at `\begin{document}`:

```
\def\document{\endgroup
  \ifx\@unusedoptionlist\@empty\else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Unused global option(s):^^J%
            \@spaces[\@unusedoptionlist]}%
  %...
```

Unknown options are kept in `\@unusedoptionlist`. So, even though `doublespacing` is passed to the document class, it is processed when [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) is loaded. From [`setspace.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty):

```
\DeclareOption{singlespacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\singlespacing}}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{doublespacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\doublespacing}}

\ProcessOptions
```